# how to show that it does not satisfy all conditions of Nested interval Theorem?

Tags: real-analysis

show that $ \ \bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}[0, \frac{1}{n}) \ \neq \phi \ \ $  but it does not satisfy Nested interval theorem conditions.

**Answer;**

Take one point $ \ \frac{1}{n} \ $ from each interval to construct the sequence $ \ \{\frac{1}{n} \} \ $ , which is a Cauchy sequence converging to $ \ 0 \ $.

But since $ \ [0,1/n) \ $ being complete , $ \ 0 \in [0,\frac{1}{n}) \ \ \forall n $

Thus,

$ \ \bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}[0, \frac{1}{n})=\{0 \} \neq \phi \ $

**But how to show that it does not satisfy all conditions of Nested interval Theorem?**

Comment: Are you sure that it does not satisfy the Nested interval Theorem?
Sets are closed (check)
Sets are nested (check)
The length goes to zero (check) ...

Comment: And besides, the intersection obviously contains $0$.

Comment: If you were asking about $\cap_1^\infty [0 \frac 1 n)$, then those intervals do not satisfy the nested interval theorem. But I think that the sets  $[0 \frac 1 n]$ *do* satisfy the nested interval theorem.

Comment: yes it is $ \cap_{n=1}^{\infty} [0,\frac{1}{n}) \ $  nut how to show it does not satisfyy Nested?

Comment: Because they are not closed in R. The condition of nested interval theorem is that the intervals have to be closed.

Comment: Is my approach to show $ \ \cap [0,1/n) =\{0 \} \ $ above correct? kindly check it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think all the $I_n$'s have to be closed.